# Terminal find, directories last instead of first

Tags: bash, makefile, terminal

I have a `makefile` that concatenates JavaScript files together and then runs the file through `uglify-js` to create a `.min.js` version.

I'm currently using this command to find and concat my files

```
find src/js -type f -name "*.js" -exec cat {} >> ${jsbuild}$@ \;
```

But it lists files in directories first, this makes heaps of sense but I'd like it to list the `.js` files in the `src/js` files **above** the directories to avoid getting my `undefined` JS error.

Is there anyway to do this or? I've had a google around and seen the [`sort`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sort.1.html) command and the `-s` flag for `find` but it's a bit above my understanding at this point!

**[EDIT]**

The final solution is slightly different to the accepted answer but it is marked as accepted as it brought me to the answer. Here is the command I used

```
cat `find src/js -type f -name "*.js" -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f "%z  %N" | sort -n | sed -e "s|[0-9]*\ \ ||"` > public/js/myCleverScript.js
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible solution:

1. use `find` for getting filenames **and directory depth**, i.e `find ...  -printf "%d\t%p\n"`
2. sort list by directory depth with `sort -n`
3. remove directory depth from output to use filenames only

test:

without sorting:

```
$ find folder1/ -depth -type f -printf "%d\t%p\n"
2   folder1/f2/f3
1   folder1/file0
```

with sorting:

```
$ find folder1/ -type f -printf "%d\t%p\n" | sort -n | sed -e "s|[0-9]*\t||"
folder1/file0
folder1/f2/f3
```

the command you need looks like

```
cat $(find src/js -type f -name "*.js" -printf "%d\t%p\n" | sort -n | sed -e "s|[0-9]*\t||")>min.js
```

Comment: Okay, this seems to work best. I had to change it to work with OSx a bit. Been a while since I used a proper *nix system. I now have `find src/js -type f -name "*.js" -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f "%z\t%N" | sort -n | sed -e "s|[0-9]\t||"` which gives me the best result thus far.

Comment: Seems like a pretty useful options this `-printf`. I should've RTFM. :-D

Answer (score 1):

Mmmmm...

```
find src/js -type f
```

shouldn't find ANY directories at all, and doubly so as your directory names will probably not end in ".js". The brackets around your "-name" parameter are superfluous too, try removing them

```
find src/js -type f -name "*.js" -exec cat {} >> ${jsbuild}$@ \;
```

Comment: Doh! Sorry, re-reading the question it made no sense. I meant it listed files in sub folders above the files in src/js which is undesired.

Answer (score 1):

`find` could get the first directory level already expanded on commandline, which enforces the order of directory tree traversal. This solves the problem just for the top directory (unlike the already accepted solution by Sergey Fedorov), but this should answer your question too and more options are always welcome.

Using GNU coreutils ls, you can sort directories before regular files with `--group-directories-first` option. From reading the [Mac OS X `ls` manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) it seems that directories are grouped always in OS X, you should just drop the option.

```
ls -A --group-directories-first -r | tac | xargs -I'%' find '%' -type f -name '*.js' -exec cat '{}' + > ${jsbuild}$@
```

If you do not have the `tac` command, you could easily implement it using `sed`. It reverses the order of lines. See `info sed tac` of GNU sed.

```
tac(){
    sed -n '1!G;$p;h'
}
```

Comment: Your solution seems to place things in an odd order, repeatable but odd where as the one provided in my edits lists in order correctly. I was just testing with `ls -A -r | sed -n '1!G;$p;h' | xargs -I'%' find '%' -type f -name '*.js' -exec cat '{}' \;`

Comment: Ah, I see. It's not grouping folders it's just sorting alphabetically.

Comment: @DaveMackintosh I do not use OS X, tested my solution only on Linux. The OS X manpage says: „If more than one operand is given, non-directory operands are displayed first; directory and non-directory operands are sorted separately and in lexicographical order.” Now I realize I misunderstood, the grouping is done only for operands. So `ls -- $(ls -A)` instead of `ls -A -r | tac`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd get the list of all the files:

```
$ find src/js -type f -name "*.js" > list.txt
```

Sort them by depth, i.e. by the number of '/' in them, using the following ruby script:

```
sort.rb:
   files=[]; while gets;  files<<$_; end
   files.sort! {|a,b| a.count('/') <=> b.count('/')}
   files.each {|f| puts f}
```

Like so:

```
$ ruby sort.rb < list.txt > sorted.txt
```

Concatenate them:

```
$ cat sorted.txt | while read FILE; do cat "$FILE" >> output.txt; done
```

(All this assumes that your file names don't contain newline characters.)

**EDIT:**

I was aiming for clarity. If you want conciseness, you can absolutely condense it to something like:

`find src/js -name '*.js'| ruby -ne 'BEGIN{f=[];}; f<<$_; END{f.sort!{|a,b| a.count("/") <=> b.count("/")}; f.each{|e| puts e}}' | xargs cat >> concatenated`

Comment: I guess you could also use `xargs` in the final step to make it shorter.

Comment: I want to avoid having to use an external script to the `makefile` to do it, is there anyway to incorporate this into the `makefile` itself?

Comment: @DaveMackintosh `find … | ruby -e 'files=[]; while …' | xargs cat > output.js` This way you can get rid of all intermediate files.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

First create a variable holding the name of our output file:

```
OUT="$(pwd)/theLot.js"
```

Then, get all "*.js" in top directory into that file:

```
cat *.js > $OUT
```

Then have "find" grab all other "*.js" files below current directory:

```
find . -type d ! -name . -exec sh -c "cd {} ; cat *.js >> $OUT" \;
```

Just to explain the "find" command, it says:

```
find
.             = starting at current directory
-type d       = all directories, not files
-! -name .    = except the current one
-exec sh -c   = and for each one you find execute the following
"..."         = go to that directory and concatenate all "*.js" files there onto end of $OUT
\;            = and that's all for today, thank you!
```